# Mathematical justification of postprocessing in QRNG

Tags: noise, hadamard

I have reading about Quantum Random Number Generators (QRNGs), and it seems that usually classical post processing is applied to the initial output of the quantum circuit to:

1. improve the quality of the number (i.e. pass more statistical test (e.g. NIST test))
2. eliminate the classical noise from the quantum signal

A typical example is the Toeplitz extractor (see for example page 8  [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.1473.pdf)). However I don't understand the mathematical justification of 2), i.e. why multiplying by such a matrix eliminates the classical noise and retain the quantum signal. Maybe is because the classical and quantum contribution follow different statistical distributions and the Toeplitz matrix cancels the classical distribution part or something but I don't find the details anywhere

Any insight?

Answer (score 4):

A QRNG contains some quantum mechanism that produces a sequence of bits $X_1X_2\dots X_n$ which are then post-processed (using a randomness extractor) to produce some final shorter random string $K_1\dots K_m$.

The goal of a QRNG is to produce the string $K_1\dots K_m$ such that the string is uniformly random (even from the perspective of some adversary $E$). The idea for the postprocessing is that by analysing the quantum device it is possible to lower bound the amount of randomness contained in $X_1\dots X_n$ which is quantified by the conditional min-entropy
$$
H_{\min}(X_1\dots X_n|E)  \geq c.
$$
with $c > m$.  From the [leftover hashing lemma](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.2436) this implies that if we apply a randomly chosen 2-universal hash function to $X_1 \dots X_n$ with output size $m$ then the output will be almost indistinguishable from $m$ uniformly random bits (even from the perspective of $E$). The goal of a QRNG is to produce uniform randomness (unknown to anyone) and so with this postprocessing it is possible.

To shed some light on question 2, I believe that classical noise is not considered "random" (because it is classical it could be copied and hence known to $E$). So when we bound $H_{\min}(X_1\dots X_n|E)$ we could assume the classical noise is part of $E$ and we could bound the amount of randomness in $X_1\dots X_n$ even when we condition on the classical noise. By the leftover hashing lemma it would then follow that the final output is uniform and independent of the classical noise in the original outputs.